# ruby - rspec - how to compare to a hash? Syntax error, unexpected =>

Tags: ruby, rspec

My hash seems to be ok, why am I getting the syntax errors ?

Getting

```
SyntaxError:
  .../x_and_o_spec.rb:14: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting '}'
      expect(board).to eq {0 =>"-", 1 =>"-",  2 =>"-",  3 =>"
                               ^
  .../x_and_o_spec.rb:14: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
   expect(board).to eq {0 =>"-", 1 =>"-",  2 =>"-",  3 =>"-", 
                                ^
  .../x_and_o_spec.rb:14: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting end-of-input
  oard).to eq {0 =>"-", 1 =>"-",  2 =>"-",  3 =>"-",  4 =>"-",
```

If i comment out my expect and just print the hash I get:

```
{0=>"-", 1=>"-", 2=>"-", 3=>"-", 4=>"-", 5=>"-", 6=>"-", 7=>"-", 8=>"-", 9=>"-"}
```

so why does my expect give those error messages ?

#### Code

```
class Grid
  attr_accessor :board
  def initialize
    @board = {}
    (0..9).each do |key|
      @board[key] = "-" 
    end 
  end 
end
```

## Test

```
it 'Grid has 9 elements, each element is a value of nil, o or X' do
  board = Grid.new.board
  expect(board).to eq {0 =>"-", 1 =>"-",  2 =>"-",  3 =>"-",  4 =>"-",  5 =>"-",  6 =>"-",  7 =>"-",  8 =>"-",  9 =>"-"}
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Programmer ignorance (me) around parser rules if the expect is a hash.
and not realizing the hash / block issue with using `{}`'s

Putting parens around it solved it!

```
 expect(board).to eq    ({0 =>"-", 1 =>"-",  ...  9 =>"-"})
 # added these parens: /\                                /\
```

Comment: Or better, say `eq(0 => '-', ...)` or `eq({ ... })` to ensure that you're using the method-calling parentheses you mean rather than expression-grouping parentheses. The underlying problem is that the braces in `eq { ... }` are block-braces, not hash-braces.

Comment: You may wish to be explicit: the error occurred because the parser interpreted `{ ... }` as a block rather than an argument. (The parser is never confused!) Further to @muistooshort's comment, in the first instance you don't even need the parentheses, but it does look odd: `def a(h); puts h; end; a 1=>'-', 2=>'!'` displays `{1=>"-", 2=>"!"}`.

Comment: This is a rule, when a hash is the first argument to a function, you must either put `()` around the arguments or remove the `{}` around the hash. For example `.to eq 0 => "-", 1 => "0"` would work fine as well

Comment: @CarySwoveland: what do you mean, "never confused"? It's clearly confused right here. "unexpected =>. What am I supposed to do with it? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯"

Comment: It's probably also fair to say that I was confused about the rules for formatting and that's why I got the code wrong.  The parser did follow (its) rules but I was unaware because I was not thinking about blocks at that point.  As usual, a communication between programmer and machine in the end.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ for a string consisting of the single ASCII character, the preferred syntax would be `?-`, not `"-"`: `@board[key] = ?-`.